# Sigfox Header Size

Tags: sigfox

I can't seem to find if the header size for Sigfox. Looking at their website (https://build.sigfox.com/study) it says "The Sigfox uplink payload is limited to 12 bytes (excluding the payload headers). The downlink payload is limited to 8 bytes (excluding the payload headers)." It never mentions anything about the size of these payload headers and I can't seem to find information on it anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's all documented in the [Sigfox device radio specifications](https://build.sigfox.com/sigfox-device-radio-specifications). For an uplink:

- 19 bits preamble
- 13 bits frame type
- 2 bits length indicator
- 1 bit bidirectional frag
- 1 bit repeated flag
- 12 bits message counter
- 32 bits identifier
- variable length uplink authentication (between 2 and 5 bytes)
- 16 bits CRC

Which gives a total of **112 to 136 bits, 14 to 17 bytes**.

Note that I just glanced at the doc, so I may have missed things, there may be more stuff.